# Connect to Azure VM from corporate networks

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, rdp, azure-sql-database

I have one question regarding Azure connection from corporate networks.
I have created a VM and a database on azure. I **can connect** to the DB and RDP to the VM from my home machine. But when I am in office, I **cannot connect** any of them. This is the error I am getting.

[image]

I thought my office proxy is causing the problem, I removed proxy connection but that did not help. I created an instance on AWS and tried connecting to the Azure VM and DB from inside that instance. But that did not help either. 
From this, I can think of only one reason that Azure does not allow incoming connection from corporate networks for free tier. I have allowed incoming request from everywhere in the rule of Azure VM and DB. 
**My azure subscription is free tier.**

Can anyone tell me if that is correct or what is the correct way to solve this problem?

***UPDATE:***  **The question is not relevant anymore. The problem was with our office network. I have created a NAT to RDP to azure machine and everything is working fine.**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Azure firewall is restricting access to your SQL server. As for your VM, you may have some ACLs set up which are restricting access.

To enable the SQL firewall rules:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

To check the ACLs on your Virtual Machine endpoints:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Comment: Checked the ACL..enabled incoming from any IP..still no luck...also to be noted my Azure VM is not under any network security group.

Comment: Azure itself does not restrict access from corporate networks. Have you compared the output of traceroute from your home machine and work machine? That might help you see where the request is getting stopped.

Comment: May be it does restrict for free tier subscription. Just checked , the request gets timeout at a point in microsoft network.

Answer (score 0):

I was onsite at a client location which disallowed outbound RDP traffic.  They set up a SOCKS proxy and installed a SOCKS client on my machine with limited rules to allow RDP to Azure.

Comment: I did a trace route and the request gets timeout at a point inside microsoft's network.